# $stateParams is getting empty value even though route has parameters

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am hitting this url

> http://localhost:8001/#/verifyMail?4c4e77a2

at that time i did

> console.log($stateParams);

It shows empty object

My route is

```
.state('mailVerification', {
        url: "/verifyMail?id",
          templateUrl: "app/views/common/emailVerification.html",
          controller: 'accountCtrl',
          data: {
              authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
          }
      })
```

Why i am not getting $stateParams.id value? Please help me.

Comment: I think the url should be like this `/verifyMail/:id`

Comment: you can try this in  url: "/verifyMail/:id"  in config module.

Comment: The url must be localhost:8001/#/verifyMail?id=4c4e77a2

Comment: @obrejacatalin, i tried this but i can't check $location.path() everytime because id is randomly generated so i want to use optional parameter

Comment: @fantarama thanks for your suggestion but it is not working

Comment: @obrejacatalin i tried it already. There was no use.

Comment: very strange, i use that notation without problem, post the controller code

Comment: @fantarama i am not doing great thing. Here i want id as optional parameter so for now i am just doing console.log(). i got empty

Comment: ok but since the state definition and url are correct without checking the whole code is not possible to help you futher

Comment: @fantarama you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912122/set-next-requested-url-with-login-if-user-is-not-logged-in?noredirect=1#comment49863515_30912122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resolve the data.

```
.state('mailVerification', {
    url: "/verifyMail?id",
      templateUrl: "app/views/common/emailVerification.html",
      resolve: {
          id: function($stateParams){
              return $stateParams.id;
          }
      }
      controller: 'accountCtrl',
      data: {
          authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
      }
  })
```

and inside the controller:

```
.controller('accountCtrl', ['id', '$log', function(id, $log){
    $log.debug(id);
}]);
```